# Grafana, range starting from specific hour

Tags: grafana

I have a prometheus metric, that is a global counter like following

**sum(increase(http_404_counter_total{namespace="XXX"}[50y]))**

I also need another counter that ranges from {today 00:00} and now(), which I will be using as "Todays counts"

Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

Edit: Grafana V7.1.5

Answer (score 2):

To select "today so far" use the following time range:

```
From: now/d
To:   now
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up achieving it by specifying the Relative Date field in Query options as "now/d"